# Initializing data members of base class using the constructor of privately derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am new to c++ programming,I am trying to execute the following code but it 
shows the error

> no matching function for call to ‘Flower::Flower()’    Rose(string n =
>   "No flower", string c = "Red") :  color(c) {}

even though i have given parametric constructor in my class Flower still it says no matching function call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Flower
{

public:
string name;


Flower (string n):name (n)
  {
  }


void getFlowerName ()
  {
    cout << name << " " << "is" << " ";
} 

};


class Rose:private Flower
{               // Inherit Flower as private
public:
string color;


    /* Initialize name and color data members */ 
Rose (string n = "No flower", string c = "Red"):color (c)
  {
  } 

void getFlowerName (Rose & r)
  {
    cout << r.color << endl;
  } 

    //  using Flower::getFlowerName ;// Allow call to  getFlowerName() method in the base class
};


class Rose:private Flower
{               // Inherit Flower as private
public:
string color;


    /* Initialize name and color data members */ 
Rose (string n = "No flower", string c = "Red"):color (c)
  {
  } 

void getFlowerName (Rose & r)
  {
    cout << r.color << endl;
  } 

using Flower::getFlowerName;    // Allow call to  getFlowerName() method in 
                                   the base class
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Derived classes should call base classes:

```
class Rose : private Flower
{
public:
    std::string color;

    Rose (const std::string& n = "No flower",
          const std::string& c = "Red") : Flower(n), color(c)
    {
    }
// ...
};
```

As currently you call implicitly the default `Flower`'s constructor, but it is not existent.

Comment: Its working fine now.Thanks for your support.But since i am new to stack overflow will you please tell me do i have to edit my answer with correct code,or i should leave it as it is.

Comment: You should **not** edit your question to invalidate already given answers.

Comment: @Ayush what you should do is accept one of the answers if it helped you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create `Flower::Flower()` default constructor.

```
Flower(){ name = NULL; }
```

Comment: `basic creator`? You mean non-parametrized constructor?

Comment: downvoted because neither "basic creator" nor "basic constructor" is the correct term. You probably meant "default constructor"

Comment: I edit my message(basic creator -> default constructor). sorry for make mistake English designation. Thank you for your advice!